# Setup - Slash Command - Nextcord

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

So i'm trying to make this bot, and i want it only to run on slash commands -
i made this command where, you have to do /setwelcome to setup your own welcome channel on each server the bot is on, but for now its only on my own server but this error shows when i start the bot.

"Error Message"
`Failed to load slash SetupSlash: Extension 'slash.SetupSlash' raised an error: AttributeError: module 'nextcord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'Option'`

This is my code:

```
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands
from nextcord import Interaction

class Setup(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    # Welcome Message
    @nextcord.slash_command(
        description="Set the welcome channel for the server",
        options=[
            commands.Option(
                name="channel_id",
                description="ID of the welcome channel",
                type=commands.OptionType.string,
                required=True
            )
        ]
    )
    async def setwelcome(self, ctx: commands.Context, channel_id: str):
        # Check if the user who triggered the command has administrator permissions
        if not ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
            await ctx.send("You need administrator permissions to use this command.", ephemeral=True)
            return

        # Check if the specified channel exists
        channel = ctx.guild.get_channel(int(channel_id))
        if not channel:
            await ctx.send("The specified channel does not exist in this server.", ephemeral=True)
            return

        # Save the channel ID as the welcome channel for the server
        self.bot.settings[ctx.guild.id]["welcome_channel"] = int(channel_id)
        # Save the settings, for example, in a JSON file or a database

        await ctx.send(f"Welcome messages will now be sent to {channel.mention}")

    # You can add a welcome message handling function here
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        guild = member.guild

        # Check if the welcome channel is set for this server
        if guild.id in self.bot.settings and "welcome_channel" in self.bot.settings[guild.id]:
            welcome_channel_id = self.bot.settings[guild.id]["welcome_channel"]
            welcome_channel = guild.get_channel(welcome_channel_id)

            if welcome_channel:
                avatar_url = member.avatar.url if member.avatar else member.default_avatar.url

                embed = nextcord.Embed(
                    title=f"Welcome to {guild.name}, {member.name}!",
                    description=f"{member.mention} We're glad to have you here. :tada:\n\n"
                                "If you have any questions or need assistance, feel free to ask. "
                                "Please remember to read the rules and enjoy your stay!",
                    color=nextcord.Color.blue()
                )

                embed.set_thumbnail(url=avatar_url)

                await welcome_channel.send(embed=embed)
            else:
                print(f"Could not find the welcome channel with ID: {welcome_channel_id}")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Setup(bot))
```

I did try change the @nextcord.slash_command to @command.slash_command but then t couln't read the code.